# Due to Java 8's new high-security restriction, would a Java Applet that runs from the desktop run without a barrage of high-security warnings?

Tags: java, security, google-chrome, npapi

I want to create an app that runs from the desktop, but if someone is using a Chrome browser and hits "Download game", would Chrome's NPAPI refusal interfere with the process at all? My other question is if they download the game, would Java 8's new high security system interfere with a convenient, easy download?

Comment: `due to Chrome's disabling of NPAPI plugins, would it also run from desktop/download fro site if they use Chrome?` it would not run in Chrome at all. `takes FOREVER to find out how to use a Java applet that is embedded on the net due to Java 8's high security.` you need to explicitly whitelist the site from which you download the applet. It is deprecated technology nowadays.

Comment: " it would not run in Chrome at all." 
Even if they hit "Download game", a mere link to the downloading of a Java Applet?

Comment: Why would you create an applet anyways. This is 2015, if you want people to play your game, make it a desktop application or use some modern technology like HTML5/Javascript/Canvas/WebGL.

Comment: Is what I am saying invisible? I said I want to create one that runs from the desktop, but IF someone is using a Chrome browser and hits "Download game", would Chrome interfere with the process at all? My other question was: IF they download the game, would Java's high security system interfere with a convenient, easy download?

Comment: @Jeff If it's a desktop application, it's not an applet.

Comment: OK, so based on such a succinct answer of whatever type of application is required for it, I will take from this that both questions have the answer of "No."

Comment: If it's a desktop runnable JAR file that you run as a runnable JAR, then it works, and Chrome won't care. But if it's an **applet** then it won't work.

Comment: Thank you! And I will assume the same is true about Java 8's security.

Answer (score 0):

No. The new security restrictions only affect Java code executing in the browser (applets and Web Start) - they do not affect file downloads, and they do not affect Java applications executing outside of a browser.

This applies even if the application happens to use applets internally.